# Specific Colour Scales For Specific Data

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

This is the last visual that i'm working on, and i'm having trouble with applying the correct colour scale for certain data groups.

The canvas is split into 3 svgs, with two donut charts within an svg set out like a column. The donut charts in the top half of the svg's belong to North England, and the bottom charts belong to the data of South England.

I've separated the names of the data into two categories, applied the colours i want, then tried an if/else statement that applies the colours (which is a technique that i've previously saw on this site and one that i've previously used). However, this isn't working for this visual... I want to up my game with programming and don't want to hardcode the colours, even though the deadline for this project is a couple of weeks away (so i have plenty of time).

Cheers

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <head>
    <title>Pie</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <style>

  .container1 {
    width: 355px;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .container2 {
    width: 355px;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translate(400px, 0px);
  }

  .container3 {
    width: 355px;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translate(800px, 0px);
  }

   </style>

   <body>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
      <div class="container1" id="svg1"></div>
      <div class="container2" id="svg2"></div>
      <div class="container3" id="svg3"></div>
  <script>

  var employed1 = [{
    City: 'Bradford City',
    Percentage: 54.63
  }, {
    City: 'Leeds',
    Percentage:62.19
  }, {
    City: 'Liverpool',
    Percentage: 55.62
  }, {
    City: 'Manchester',
    Percentage: 60.50
  }, {
    City: 'Sheffield',
    Percentage: 59.03
  }];

  var employed2 = [{
    City: 'Brighton',
    Percentage: 65.29
  }, {
    City: 'Bristol',
    Percentage: 66.72
  }, {
    City: 'Luton',
    Percentage: 62.87
  }, {
    City: 'Milton Keynes',
    Percentage: 67.80
  }, {
    City: 'Southampton',
    Percentage: 67.36,
  }];

  var unemployed1 = [{
    City: 'Bradford City',
    Percentage: 15.52
  }, {
    City: 'Leeds',
    Percentage: 6.96
  }, {
    City: 'Liverpool',
    Percentage: 9.76
  }, {
    City: 'Manchester',
    Percentage: 10.71
  }, {
    City: 'Sheffield',
    Percentage: 5.33
  }];

  var unemployed2 = [{
    City: 'Brighton',
    Percentage: 5.33
  }, {
    City: 'Bristol',
    Percentage: 5.51
  }, {
    City: 'Luton',
    Percentage: 8.50
  }, {
    City: 'Milton Keynes',
    Percentage: 5.17
  }, {
    City: 'Southampton',
    Percentage: 5.44
  }];

  var other3 = [{
    City: 'Bradford City',
    Percentage: 29.85
  }, {
    City: 'Leeds',
    Percentage: 30.85
  }, {
    City: 'Liverpool',
    Percentage: 34.62
  }, {
    City: 'Manchester',
    Percentage: 28.79
  }, {
    City: 'Sheffield',
    Percentage: 33.76
  }];

  var other4 = [{
    City: 'Bradford City',
    Percentage: 29.38
  }, {
    City: 'Leeds',
    Percentage: 27.77
  }, {
    City: 'Liverpool',
    Percentage: 28.63
  }, {
    City: 'Manchester',
    Percentage: 27.03
  }, {
    City: 'Sheffield',
    Percentage: 27.30
}];

const NE = ["Bradford City", "Leeds", "Liverpool", "Manchester", "Sheffield"];

var colorNE = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(NE)
  .range(["#A8A7A7", "#2F9599", "#E8175D", "#474747", "#CC527A"]);

const SE = ["Brighton", "Bristol", "Luton", "Milton Keynes", "Southampton"];

var colorSE = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(SE)
  .range(["#F8B195", "#F67280", "#C06C84", "#6C5B7B", "#355C7D"]);

   var mentalHealthAndAlcoholPie = d3.pie()
      .value(function(d) {
      return d.Percentage
   })
   .sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.City.localeCompare(b.City);
   });

var arcGenerator = d3.arc()
   .innerRadius(100)
   .outerRadius(135)
   .padAngle(.02)
   .padRadius(50);

   draw("svg1", employed1);
   draw("svg1", employed2);
   draw("svg2", unemployed1);
   draw("svg2", unemployed2);
   draw("svg3", other3);
   draw("svg3", other4);

function draw(selector, data) {

var arcData = mentalHealthAndAlcoholPie(data);

var svg = d3.select("#" + selector)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1000)
  .attr("height", 450)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(200, 250)");

svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(arcData)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    var result = null;

      if (NE.indexOf(d.data.name) >= 0) {
        result = colorNE(d.data.name);
      } if else (SE.indexOf(d.data.name) >= 0) {
        result = colorSE(d.data.name);
      } else {

      result = "white";
    }
    return result;
  })
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .attr('d', arcGenerator);

svg.append("text")
.selectAll('text')
.data(arcData)
.enter()
.append('text')
.each(function(d) {
  var centroid = arcGenerator.centroid(d);
  d3.select(this)
    .attr('x', centroid[0])
    .attr('y', centroid[1])
    .attr('dy', '0.30em')
    .text(d.label)
});
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your JS code has two mistakes : `if else (...` - wrong operators order, `d.data.name` should be `d.data.City`

```
  if (NE.indexOf(d.data.name) >= 0) {
    result = colorNE(d.data.name);
  } if else (SE.indexOf(d.data.name) >= 0) {
    result = colorSE(d.data.name);
  } else {
```

Please see the fixed version snippet:

```js
var employed1 = [{
  City: 'Bradford City',
  Percentage: 54.63
}, {
  City: 'Leeds',
  Percentage: 62.19
}, {
  City: 'Liverpool',
  Percentage: 55.62
}, {
  City: 'Manchester',
  Percentage: 60.50
}, {
  City: 'Sheffield',
  Percentage: 59.03
}];

var employed2 = [{
  City: 'Brighton',
  Percentage: 65.29
}, {
  City: 'Bristol',
  Percentage: 66.72
}, {
  City: 'Luton',
  Percentage: 62.87
}, {
  City: 'Milton Keynes',
  Percentage: 67.80
}, {
  City: 'Southampton',
  Percentage: 67.36,
}];

var unemployed1 = [{
  City: 'Bradford City',
  Percentage: 15.52
}, {
  City: 'Leeds',
  Percentage: 6.96
}, {
  City: 'Liverpool',
  Percentage: 9.76
}, {
  City: 'Manchester',
  Percentage: 10.71
}, {
  City: 'Sheffield',
  Percentage: 5.33
}];

var unemployed2 = [{
  City: 'Brighton',
  Percentage: 5.33
}, {
  City: 'Bristol',
  Percentage: 5.51
}, {
  City: 'Luton',
  Percentage: 8.50
}, {
  City: 'Milton Keynes',
  Percentage: 5.17
}, {
  City: 'Southampton',
  Percentage: 5.44
}];

var other3 = [{
  City: 'Bradford City',
  Percentage: 29.85
}, {
  City: 'Leeds',
  Percentage: 30.85
}, {
  City: 'Liverpool',
  Percentage: 34.62
}, {
  City: 'Manchester',
  Percentage: 28.79
}, {
  City: 'Sheffield',
  Percentage: 33.76
}];

var other4 = [{
  City: 'Bradford City',
  Percentage: 29.38
}, {
  City: 'Leeds',
  Percentage: 27.77
}, {
  City: 'Liverpool',
  Percentage: 28.63
}, {
  City: 'Manchester',
  Percentage: 27.03
}, {
  City: 'Sheffield',
  Percentage: 27.30
}];

const NE = ["Bradford City", "Leeds", "Liverpool", "Manchester", "Sheffield"];

var colorNE = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(NE)
  .range(["#A8A7A7", "#2F9599", "#E8175D", "#474747", "#CC527A"]);

const SE = ["Brighton", "Bristol", "Luton", "Milton Keynes", "Southampton"];

var colorSE = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(SE)
  .range(["#F8B195", "#F67280", "#C06C84", "#6C5B7B", "#355C7D"]);

var mentalHealthAndAlcoholPie = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.Percentage
  })
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.City.localeCompare(b.City);
  });

var arcGenerator = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(100)
  .outerRadius(135)
  .padAngle(.02)
  .padRadius(50);

draw("svg1", employed1);
draw("svg1", employed2);
draw("svg2", unemployed1);
draw("svg2", unemployed2);
draw("svg3", other3);
draw("svg3", other4);

function draw(selector, data) {

  var arcData = mentalHealthAndAlcoholPie(data);

  var svg = d3.select("#" + selector)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 450)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(200, 250)");

  svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(arcData)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      var result = null;

      if (NE.indexOf(d.data.City) >= 0) {
        result = colorNE(d.data.City);
      } else if (SE.indexOf(d.data.City) >= 0) {
        result = colorSE(d.data.City);
      } else {

        result = "white";
      }
      return result;
    })
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .attr('d', arcGenerator);

  svg.append("text")
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(arcData)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .each(function(d) {
      var centroid = arcGenerator.centroid(d);
      d3.select(this)
        .attr('x', centroid[0])
        .attr('y', centroid[1])
        .attr('dy', '0.30em')
        .text(d.label)
    });
}
```

```css
.container1 {
  width: 355px;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.container2 {
  width: 355px;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: translate(400px, 0px);
}

.container3 {
  width: 355px;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: translate(800px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<div class="container1" id="svg1"></div>
<div class="container2" id="svg2"></div>
<div class="container3" id="svg3"></div>
```

Comment: @GeorgeGilliland, your code had errors which I've found and fixed. Aditya K edited your question and pasted the fixed code there.

Comment: @GeorgeGilliland, I've rolled back your question to the first version with your original code

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [d3 color schemes](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#color-schemes-d3-scale-chromatic). You will have to change your scales like this:

```
var colorNE = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
  .domain(NE);

var colorSE = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20)
  .domain(SE);
```

But then your data must be in the same sequence always (according to the City name) which is bad idea. You're better off creating your own scale.

Comment: I am using my own colour scheme? But I think the issue lies in the if/else statement?

Comment: I had changed the code so that the fiddle works. Did you ask for a code correction or a solution for your color scales?